# React-Native:Requested keys of a value that is not an object

Tags: react-native, react-native-listview

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, ListView, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { ItemOverView } from '../../components/common';
import * as actions from '../../actions';

class AwaitingScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
  header: null,
  };

  state = { loading: true };

  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.getAwaitingOrders();
    this.createDataSource(this.props);
  }
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.setState({ loading: false });
    this.createDataSource(nextProps);
  }
  createDataSource({ orders }) {
    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({
      rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2
    });
    this.dataSource = ds.cloneWithRows(orders);
  }

  renderListView() {
    if (this.state.loading) {
      return (<ActivityIndicator
        size='large'
        color='#397af8'
      />
    );
    }
    return (
      <ListView
        enableEmptySections
        dataSource={this.dataSource}
        renderRow={this.renderRow}
      />
    );
  }
  renderRow = (order) => {
    return (
      <ItemOverView
        item={order}
      />
    );
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        {this.renderListView()}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    awaitingOrders: state.orders.awaitingOrders,
    statusCodes: state.orders.statusCodes
  };
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(AwaitingScreen);
```

the error is for the 
this.createDataSource(this.props) as is doesn't recognise it as object,
first the awaitingOrder is an empty array, then when i request to a server, i get a array...
For example `[{ "product": "productname"}, {"product": "anotherproduct"}]`
but i am not able to render the listview for some reason

```
INITIAL STATE = awaitingOrders: []
```

when i put `this.createDataSource(['hello','hello']);`
it works..but i can't find anything wrong in my code too
It would be really helpful if someone will help

Comment: You're only calling `this.setState({ loading: false });` in `componentWillReceiveProps`, which is NOT called when the component is initially mounted.  Is that why you think you can't "render the list"?

Comment: no, i solved it...i was passing { order } to createDataSource...then i changed it to order,,,I think it was taking it as an object not array